# What is the difference between 很 + adjective and adjective + 得很

Tags: word-choice, adjectives

Since learning the adjective + 得很 rule I have only seen it once in writing with a two syllable adjective。
What are the differences in register and／or meaning between 很 + adjective and adjective+得很？

Comment: Example: 很懒 or 懒得很

Comment: The form 很 + adj is commonly seen in Mandarin, while adj + 得很 is rarely used in  Mandarin or official occasion like TV programs, but common in most northern dialects.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not a linguist. As Chinese is my first language, I can describe how I use these 2 words.
很is like English word 'very', its place in a sentence is aways before another adjective. While 得很 is more intense, and it usually follows another adjective.
For example:  a, 这件东西很好。b,这件东西好得很。Both sentence a and b mean 'This thing is very good.', but sentence b is stronger in feelings.

---

**很 + adjective** can be followed by nouns, but **adjective + 得很** can not.

For example: 很高的山峰

But we don't say: 高得很的山峰. It is just wrong.

I would say **adjective + 得很** alomst always comes (with or without modal particle) at the end of a sentence.

For example:

这屋子 **脏得很** 。

你的字， **好得很嘛** 。你怎么说不好呢？

Comment: Thanks, but what about the difference in formality?

Comment: @tao The two can both be formal. Adding to the answer that `得很` can be used to emphasize a property in a large degree. Say `这件东西好得很！` can be interpreted like `This thing is exceptionally great!`. In another way, if `很好` means 5 out of 10, `好得很` can be used for higher scores, like 9/10.